# I don't exactly understand this basic java program

Tags: java, io

As I'm extremely new to java, I seem to have trouble grasping some concepts. Here is a program. I understand the `System.out` part reasonably well but am having trouble getting my head around how the input works.

```
// IO Example:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloAge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What's your name? ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("In which year were you born? ");
        Integer birthyear = in.nextInt();
        Integer age = 2011 - birthyear;
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!  Welcome to COMP1100.\n" +
                           "You will turn " + age + " this year.");
    }
}
```

I can't see why there is `in.nextLine();` and then `in.nextInt();` I don't see what those two commands have in common or what they're supposed to mean? That's my main issue.

Comment: SO has plenty of answers linking to introductory java tutorials

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Where could I find those?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?  How the Scanner works?  What those method calls do?  What is your current understanding with the input code?

Comment: @maclunian: perhaps start by searching SO...  Google tip:   site:stackoverflow.com "search words"

Comment: I can't see why there is `in.nextLine();` and then `in.nextInt();` I don't see what those two commands have in common or what they're supposed to mean??? That's my main issue.

Comment: @maclunian - Lesson #1 - learn to use the javadocs - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/.  In this case, the javadoc for Scanner (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) describes those methods.  If you read the descriptions for the class and the methods, you should be able to see what they have in common and how they differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general try the javadocs first; in this case the [Scanner docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

First create a new scanner for reading stdin...

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Read in the entire next line which is all chars up to the next newline...

```
String name = in.nextLine();
```

Read the next set of chars as an integer...

```
Integer birthyear = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: So basically should you use `in.NextLine();` when the next line deals with Strings and `in.nextInt();` when the next line deals with Integers? Am I on the right track?

Comment: replace the words "next line" with "next set of characters" and you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

System.in calls input from the console. The Scanner then reads that input data and puts it into whatever format. The in.nextVar is the function that takes the data and reads one 'chunk' of data, and puts it into the specified format.

Answer (score 0):

You can may be find your answer in [this tutorial](http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html) on the scanner object.